# Hyperledger fablic discovery service shows peers only for one organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I'm having issues with discovery service, it returns peers only for current altho second org have joined channel and invoked some chaincodes there.

```
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.com:7051
```

here are gossip env variables for peer of second org and record from config

```
- &org1

    Name: org1

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: org1MSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: /private/orgs/org1/msp

    AnchorPeers:
       # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
       # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
       # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
       - Host: peer1.org1.com
         Port: 7051
```

can somebody help me with this?
Fabric version 1.4

Comment: When you joined peers to the channel did you then update the channel config to include the anchor peer(s) for each organization?

Comment: I didn't, I thought I did but only generated anchor update tx without applying it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Excellent ... glad things are working